# How do I add a scroll bar in a null layout?

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane, layout-manager, null-layout-manager

I have been trying to get a scroll bar on my `JTextArea` for days, I've tried every way to do it as I could find. I am making a Chat Client and I have the JPanel setup with a null layout. I've tried using the Layout Managers but I don't understand how to get it to look the way I want.

I just want a scroll bar on the text area. I'm a beginner and for what I've read it isn't possible to have one with a null layout? I'm open to help changing the layout if that's easier also.

[image: Chat Server Client]

```
package guiserver;

import com.apple.eawt.Application;
import java.awt.Canvas;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JPasswordField;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JSplitPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;

public class GUIserver extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

JFrame login = new JFrame();
JPanel panel = new JPanel();
JPanel main = new JPanel();
JFrame accept = new JFrame();
JPanel acpt = new JPanel();
JPanel buttonpanel = new JPanel();
JButton acceptinvite = new JButton("Accept Invite");
JButton denyinvite = new JButton("Deny Invite");
JLabel acceptlabel = new JLabel();
JLabel acceptname = new JLabel();
JPanel loginpanel = new JPanel();
JTextArea chat = new JTextArea(" Waiting to Start Client...");
JSplitPane chatsplit = new JSplitPane(JSplitPane.VERTICAL_SPLIT);
JTextField input = new JTextField();
JScrollPane pane = new JScrollPane(chat);
JButton send = new JButton("Send");
JLabel IP = new JLabel("IP:... ");
JButton start = new JButton("Start");
sendThread s1 = new sendThread();
fromThread f1 = new fromThread();
infoFromThread f2 = new infoFromThread();
infoToThread s2 = new infoToThread();
RPSpickTimer pt = new RPSpickTimer();
myCanvas contact = new myCanvas();
myCanvas logo = new myCanvas();
JButton rock = new JButton("Rock");
JButton paper = new JButton("Paper");
JButton scissors = new JButton("Scissors");
JTextField username = new JTextField();
JLabel loguser = new JLabel("Username:");
JLabel logpass = new JLabel("Password:");
JPasswordField password = new JPasswordField();
JButton signin = new JButton("Sign in");
String inputText = "0";
String chatCurrent;
String out1;
String in;
boolean pause = true;
boolean rps = false;
int P1pick = 0;
int P2pick = 0;
String user = "User 1";
String user2 = "Jacob Abthorpe";
String pass;
int badge;
int sendinvite = 0;
char answerinvite = '-';
boolean pauseInfo = true;
int winner = 0;

public GUIserver() {
    Application application = Application.getApplication();
    Image image = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("src/icon.png");
    application.setDockIconImage(image);

    login.setVisible(true);
    login.setSize(400, 500);
    login.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    login.setTitle("Login");
    login.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    login.add(loginpanel);
    loginpanel.setLayout(null);
    loginpanel.add(username);
    loginpanel.add(password);
    loginpanel.add(signin);
    loginpanel.add(logpass);
    loginpanel.add(loguser);
    loginpanel.add(logo);
    login.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
    username.setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.CENTER);
    password.setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.CENTER);
    username.setBounds(50, 290, 300, 30);
    password.setBounds(50, 350, 300, 30);
    loguser.setBounds(55, 265, 300, 30);
    logpass.setBounds(55, 325, 300, 30);
    signin.setBounds(150, 400, 100, 30);
    logo.setBounds(110, 50, 150, 150);
    username.addActionListener(this);
    password.addActionListener(this);
    signin.addActionListener(this);

    setVisible(false);
    setSize(500, 600);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setTitle("Chat Server Client");
    setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setAlwaysOnTop(true);
    panel.setLayout(null);
    panel.setLocation(300, 0);
    panel.add(pane);
    panel.add(input);
    panel.add(send);
    panel.add(IP);
    panel.add(start);
    panel.add(rock);
    panel.add(paper);
    panel.add(scissors);
    contact.picx = 120;
    contact.picy = 120;
    contact.setBackground(Color.white);
    contact.setBounds(370, 10, 120, 120);
    panel.add(contact);
    input.addActionListener(this);
    send.addActionListener(this);
    start.addActionListener(this);
    rock.addActionListener(this);
    paper.addActionListener(this);
    scissors.addActionListener(this);
    chat.setEditable(false);
    pane.setBounds(10, 10, 350, 450);
    input.setEditable(false);
    input.setBounds(10, 470, 350, 80);
    start.setBounds(370, 470, 115, 80);
    IP.setBounds(15, 520, 480, 80);
    rock.setVisible(false);
    paper.setVisible(false);
    scissors.setVisible(false);
    scissors.setBounds(370, 430, 115, 30);
    paper.setBounds(370, 400, 115, 30);
    rock.setBounds(370, 370, 115, 30);
    setContentPane(panel);


    accept.setVisible(false);
    accept.setSize(400, 125);
    accept.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    accept.setTitle("Rock, Paper, Scissors");
    accept.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
    accept.setResizable(false);
    accept.add(acpt);
    acpt.setLayout(null);
    acpt.add(acceptlabel);
    acpt.add(buttonpanel);
    acpt.add(acceptname);
    buttonpanel.setBounds(0, 60, 400, 40);
    buttonpanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    acceptlabel.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
    acceptlabel.setText("would like to play Rock, Paper, Scissors. Accept?");
    acceptlabel.setBounds(0, 25, 400, 40);
    acceptname.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
    acceptname.setText(user2 + "");
    acceptname.setBounds(0, 3, 400, 40);
    buttonpanel.add(acceptinvite);
    buttonpanel.add(denyinvite);
    acceptinvite.addActionListener(this);
    denyinvite.addActionListener(this);
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if (e.getSource() == input) {
        if (input.getText().startsWith("/")) {
            if (input.getText().contentEquals("/")) {
                chat.append("\n\n >Type '/help' for list of all commands");
            }
            if (input.getText().contentEquals("/start RPS")) {
                chat.append("\n \n >Waiting for opponent to accept invite. . .");
                pauseInfo = false;
                sendinvite = 10;
            }
            if (input.getText().contentEquals("/help")) {
                chat.append("\n\n >Type '/help' for list of all commands");
                chat.append("\n >Type '/start RPS' to play Rock Paper Scissors");
                chat.append("\n >Type '/end' to quit current game");
            }
            if (input.getText().contentEquals("/end")) {
                if (rps == true) {
                    chat.append("\n\n >Quiting Rock, Paper, Scissors. . .");
                    rps = false;
                    rock.setVisible(false);
                    paper.setVisible(false);
                    scissors.setVisible(false);
                }
            }
            input.setText("");
        } else {
            if ((input.getText().contentEquals("")) && (input.getText().contentEquals(" "))) {
                Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().beep();
            } else {
                pause = false;
                chat.append("\n \n " + user + " says: \n        " + input.getText());
                inputText = input.getText();
                input.setText("");
            }
        }
    }
    if (e.getSource() == send) {
        //chat.append("\n \n Dale Schmidt says: \n        " + inputText);
        //pause = false;
    }
    if (e.getSource() == username) {
        user = username.getText();
    }
    if (e.getSource() == signin) {
        login.setVisible(false);
        setVisible(true);
    }
    if (e.getSource() == start) {
        try {
            s1.start();
            f1.start();
            s2.start();
            f2.start();
            setAlwaysOnTop(false);
            chat.append("\n " + InetAddress.getLocalHost() + "\n Server started.");
            IP.setText("IP: " + InetAddress.getLocalHost());
            start.setVisible(false);
            send.setVisible(true);
            input.setEditable(true);
            send.setBounds(370, 470, 115, 80);
        } catch (Exception s) {
            System.out.print("YOLOerror starting server");
        }
    }
    if (e.getSource() == rock) {
        if ((rps == true) && (P1pick == 0)) {
            P1pick = 1;
            chat.append("\n\n >You picked 'Rock'");
            if (P2pick != 0) {
                pt.start();
            }
        }
    }
    if (e.getSource() == paper) {
        if ((rps == true) && (P1pick == 0)) {
            P1pick = 2;
            chat.append("\n\n >You picked 'Paper'");
            if (P2pick != 0) {
                pt.start();
            }
        }
    }
    if (e.getSource() == scissors) {
        if ((rps == true) && (P1pick == 0)) {
            P1pick = 3;
            chat.append("\n\n >You picked 'Scissors'");
            if (P2pick != 0) {
                pt.start();
            }
        }
    }
    if (e.getSource() == acceptinvite) {
        rps = true;
        rock.setVisible(true);
        paper.setVisible(true);
        scissors.setVisible(true);
        answerinvite = 'y';
        accept.dispose();
    }
    if (e.getSource() == denyinvite) {
        answerinvite = 'n';
        accept.dispose();
    }
}

class myCanvas extends Canvas {

    int x = 10, y = 10;
    int picx = 150, picy = 150;

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        Image image1 = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("src/icon.png");
        g.drawImage(image1, x, y, picx, picy, this);
    }
}    

class sendThread extends Thread {

    ServerSocket s1;
    Socket sendclientSocket = null;

    public void run() {
        inputText = input.getText();
        try {
            System.err.println("Starting Send Server");
            System.out.println(InetAddress.getLocalHost());
            s1 = new ServerSocket(4444);
            sendclientSocket = s1.accept();
            System.err.println("Started Send Server");
        } catch (Exception s1) {
            System.exit(1);
        }
        while (true) {
            try {
                PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(sendclientSocket.getOutputStream(), true);

                if (pause == false) {
                    badge = 0;
                    out.println(input.getText());
                    System.out.println("sent");
                    pause = true;
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.err.println("Error Sending.");
                System.err.println(e.getMessage());
                System.exit(2);
            }
        }
    }
}

class fromThread extends Thread {

    ServerSocket s2;
    Socket fromclientSocket = null;

    public void run() {
        try {
            System.err.println("Starting Recieve Server");
            s2 = new ServerSocket(4441);
            fromclientSocket = s2.accept();
            System.err.println("Started Recieve Server");
        } catch (Exception s2) {
            System.exit(1);
        }

        while (true) {
            try {

                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fromclientSocket.getInputStream()));

                String fromClient = in.readLine();

                if (fromClient.contentEquals("")) {

                } else {                        
                    Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().beep();
                    chat.append("\n\n " + user2 + " says:\n        " + fromClient);
                    badge++;
                    Application.getApplication().setDockIconBadge(Integer.toString(badge));
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.err.println("Error Receiving.");
                System.err.println(e.getMessage());
                System.exit(3);
            }
        }
    }
}

class infoFromThread extends Thread {

    ServerSocket s3;
    Socket infoFromClientSocket = null;

    public void run() {
        try {
            s3 = new ServerSocket(4446);
            infoFromClientSocket = s3.accept();
        } catch (Exception s3) {
            System.exit(7);
        }

        while (true) {
            try {

                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(infoFromClientSocket.getInputStream()));

                String infoFromClient = in.readLine();

                if (infoFromClient.contentEquals("10")) {
                    accept.setVisible(true);
                    sendinvite = 0;
                } else if (infoFromClient.contentEquals("y")) {
                    chat.append("\n >Invite Accepted");
                    rps = true;
                    rock.setVisible(true);
                    paper.setVisible(true);
                    scissors.setVisible(true);
                    answerinvite = '-';
                } else if (infoFromClient.contentEquals("n")) {
                    chat.append("\n\n >Invite Declined");
                    answerinvite = '-';
                } else if (infoFromClient.contentEquals("1")) {
                    chat.append("\n\n >Opponent made selection");
                    P2pick = 1;
                    if (P1pick != 0) {
                        pt.start();
                    }
                } else if (infoFromClient.contentEquals("2")) {
                    chat.append("\n\n >Opponent made selection");
                    P2pick = 2;
                    if (P1pick != 0) {
                        pt.start();
                    }
                } else if (infoFromClient.contentEquals("3")) {
                    chat.append("\n\n >Opponent made selection");
                    P2pick = 3;
                    if (P1pick != 0) {
                        pt.start();
                    }
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.err.println("Error Receiving Information.");
                System.err.println(e.getMessage());
                System.exit(3);
            }
        }
    }
}

class infoToThread extends Thread {

    ServerSocket s4;
    Socket infoToClientSocket = null;

    public void run() {
        inputText = input.getText();
        try {
            s4 = new ServerSocket(4447);
            infoToClientSocket = s4.accept();
        } catch (Exception s4) {
            System.exit(8);
        }
        while (true) {
            try {
                PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(infoToClientSocket.getOutputStream(), true);

                if (sendinvite == 10) {
                    out.println(sendinvite);
                    sendinvite = 0;
                    pauseInfo = false;
                }
                if ((answerinvite == 'y') || (answerinvite == 'n')) {
                    out.println(answerinvite);
                    answerinvite = '-';
                }

                    if (winner == 1) {
                        out.println("Loser");
                    }
                    else if (winner == 2) {
                        out.println("Winner");
                    }
                    else if (winner == 3) {
                        out.println("Tie");
                    }
                    //winner = 0;

                //System.err.println("infoToClient");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.err.println("Error Sending Information.");
                System.err.println(e.getMessage());
                System.exit(2);
            }
        }
    }
}
class RPSpickTimer extends Thread {

    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            try {
                if (P1pick != 0) {
                if (P1pick == 1) {
                    if (P2pick == 1) {
                        //tie
                        chat.append("\n\n Tie!");
                        winner = 3;
                    } else if (P2pick == 2) {
                        //P2wins
                        chat.append("\n\n " + user2 + " wins!");
                        winner = 2;
                    } else if (P2pick == 3) {
                        //P1wins
                        chat.append("\n\n " + user + " wins!");
                        winner = 1;
                    }

                } else if (P1pick == 2) {
                    if (P2pick == 1) {
                        //P1wins
                        chat.append("\n\n " + user + " wins!");
                        winner = 1;
                    } else if (P2pick == 2) {
                        //tie
                        chat.append("\n\n Tie!");
                        winner = 3;
                    } else if (P2pick == 3) {
                        //P2wins
                        chat.append("\n\n " + user2 + " wins!");
                        winner = 2;
                    }

                } else if (P1pick == 3) {
                    if (P2pick == 1) {
                        //P2wins
                        chat.append("\n\n " + user2 + " wins!");
                        winner = 2;
                    } else if (P2pick == 2) {
                        //P1wins
                        chat.append("\n\n " + user + " wins!");
                        winner = 1;
                    } else if (P2pick == 3) {
                        //tie
                        chat.append("\n\n Tie!");
                        winner = 3;
                    }
                }
                P1pick = 0;
                P2pick = 0;
            }
            else {
                sleep(250);
            }  

            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.err.println("Error Picking Winner.");
                System.err.println(e.getMessage());
                System.exit(2);
            }
        }
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    GUIserver s = new GUIserver();

}`
```

Comment: General advice is not to use a null layout. Swing was designed around the concept of layout managers

Comment: Where is that vertical alignment at!

Comment: instead of null layout use other layout,other layout provide you more facilities.May this help you http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/scrollpane.html

Comment: @MadProgrammer How would you suggest using the layout managers? I realize that using the layouts is the proper way to do it but I looked into it and I couldn't figure out a way to make it look like how mine is set up now.

Comment: I've not looked to deeply into your code, but sometng like GridBagLayout should be able to achieve what you want

Comment: @Dale While not answer to your direct problem, I've done a mock up of how you might be able to use layout managers to produce the same UI

Comment: To expand on the advice of @MadProgrammer.  Java GUIs might have to work on a number of platforms, on different screen resolutions & using different PLAFs.  As such they are not conducive to exact placement of components.  To organize the components for a robust GUI, instead use layout managers, or [combinations of them](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556), along with layout padding & borders for [white space](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17874717/418556).

Comment: Note:  I wanted to compile that code to see the layout you were trying to achieve.  Unfortunately after copy/pasting the code, adding a closing `}` at the end of the source, and adding `import` statements, it still has 15 compile errors for missing custom classes.  For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @AndrewThompson Added MCVE

Comment: ...you really think 550+ lines of code is 'minimal'?  Two further notes.  1) `import com.apple.eawt.Application;` That is only available on OS X, so I could not compile it here on Windows. 2) A layout problem does not need to use classes in `java.io`, `java.net` (usually) or `java.awt.event`..  Please do us all a favor and *really* try to either trim the code down to minimal, or build up *only* the layout.  I would guess that minimal in this case comes to around 80-120 LOC.

Comment: Try javabuilders which splits gui layout from your chat logic. It also comes with MiG layout which is very intuitive and easy to use with the above package.

Comment: @Pureferret  I liked that comment right up until the mention of `MigLayout`.  Don't get me wrong, it's a great layout. Unfortunately it is a 3rd party layout, so if code used it, most people could not compile it.

Comment: @AndrewThompson This is for a high school class. I haven't been creating it with running on different OS's in mind. I know my code is a mess but my teacher hasn't been a lot of help; most of the things I've been doing he doesn't even teach. I will probably look into doing this properly with my next program but it's due next week and all I needed was scrolling. Thanks for your help.

Comment: *"I know my code is a mess but my teacher hasn't been a lot of help;"*  Please don't mention the teacher in future.  Most people think 'It is a poor workman that blames the tools'.  Instead I'll refer you to a great resource that most of the people who helped solve this learned from.  The Java Tutorial has a great section on [Creating a GUI With JFC/Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/).  You might note that is an entire 'Trail', with multiple Lessons, and therefore might seem daunting.  OTOH, by the 3rd GUI you make, it will have saved time to go through it.

Comment: @AndrewThompson how so? If you download the dependancies for javabuilders it comes bundled in the zip. Javabuilders supports cardlayout and flowlayout as well.

Comment: Dale, if this is you first go at GUIs follow Andrew's advice. The tutorials ae great.

Comment: @Pureferret  While I use both NetBeans and Eclipse for 'real world' projects, I use (an ancient version of) TextPad for checking MCVE code.  I do that for a couple of reasons, the primary one being that it is 'a few keystrokes less' to see an MCVE on-screen.  Given I deal with a lot of short codes like that, it saves me a lot of typing.  Also, ..I just don't tend to use GUI builders even when using an IDE (but that's another story..).

Comment: @AndrewThompson I'm not blaming him. I'm stating that he simply does not care enough to properly help me get this right. I know this because I'm going to get a 100% on my program and he told me that days ago. People can think what they want; you can't tell me you've never had a teacher that you thought could have taught you better.

Comment: *"..you can't tell me you've never had a teacher that you thought could have taught you better."*  I'm not telling you that.  It is just the opposite.  Note that I prefixed the tip with 'most people' - it is really just an observation based on experience, rather than what I feel personally.  I wish you all the best with your learning of Java.  :)

Comment: @AndrewThompson I don't use graphical drag-and-drop gui builder's,  I don't trust anything that writes code for me. Javabuilders just let's you define your view in Yaml. I'm not sure what mvce is though...

Comment: *"Javabuilders just let's you define your view in Yaml."*  Or right.. My bad. *"I'm not sure what mvce is though.."*  The [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) is the 'Stack Exchange friendly' replacement for SSCCE (I hope you know what I mean by SSCCE, since I'd prefer *not* to link to it).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line:

```
panel.add(chat);
```

Instead of adding `chat`, add `pane`, like:

```
panel.add(pane);
```

Comment: Duh! Thank you, I had tried that but did change the setBounds to match the pane. So when I ran the program it would be blank.

Answer (score 2):

From [JTextArea](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextArea.html) docs "The java.awt.TextArea internally handles scrolling. JTextArea is different in that it doesn't manage scrolling, but implements the swing Scrollable interface. This allows it to be placed inside a JScrollPane if scrolling behavior is desired, and used directly if scrolling is not desired."

I think that means that this is what you want:

```
JTextArea chat = new JTextArea(" Waiting to Start Client...");
JScrollPane chatScrollPane = new JScrollPane(chat);

...

panel.setLocation(300, 0);
panel.add(chatScrollPane);
panel.add(input);
```

As Nicolás Carlo pointed out, you already have the JScrollPane and just need to add it instead of the JTextArea.  Basically the Java UI system (and most UI systems) are a giant tree of widgets. If you don't add a widget to the tree it doesn't have an effect. In this case, the JScrollPane wasn't getting added to the tree and therefore wasn't doing anything for you.

Comment: I know its hard to read in the code, but he has a jscrollpane, he just added jtextarea again instead of adding his jscrollpane to the panel. +1 for the reference.

Answer (score 2):

***This is not an answer, but a demonstration of how a `LayoutManager` might be used to achieve the OP's results***

So, based on your code example, I get this output...

[image: BadLayout]

I hope you note that the frame isn't big enough to hold the content, this is the major problem with `null` layouts, they never look the same on other systems...

And by utilising a `GridBagLayout` and a `GridLayout` and a concept known as "compound layouts", I was able to mock this...

[image: BetterLayout]

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class ChatLayout {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new ChatLayout();
    }

    public ChatLayout() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new ChatPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class ChatPane extends JPanel {

        private JTextArea chatWindow;
        private JTextField input;
        private JLabel ipLabel;

        private JButton rockBtn;
        private JButton paperBtn;
        private JButton scissorsBtn;
        private JButton startBtn;

        public ChatPane() {

            JPanel leftPane = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
            JPanel rightPane = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());

            chatWindow = new JTextArea(20, 40);
            chatWindow.setText("Waiting to start chat...");

            input = new JTextField(10);
            ipLabel = new JLabel("IP...");

            rockBtn = new JButton("Rock");
            paperBtn = new JButton("Paper");
            scissorsBtn = new JButton("Scissors");
            startBtn = new JButton("Start");

            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.insets = new Insets(4, 4, 4, 4);
            gbc.gridx = 0;
            gbc.gridy = 0;
            gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
            gbc.weighty = 1;
            gbc.weightx = 1;
            leftPane.add(new JScrollPane(chatWindow), gbc);

            gbc.gridy++;
            gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
            gbc.weighty = 0;
            gbc.weightx = 1;
            gbc.gridheight = 1;
            leftPane.add(input, gbc);

            gbc.gridy++;
            gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
            leftPane.add(ipLabel, gbc);

            JPanel buttonsPane = new JPanel(new GridLayout(3, 1));
            buttonsPane.add(rockBtn);
            buttonsPane.add(paperBtn);
            buttonsPane.add(scissorsBtn);

            gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.gridx = 0;
            gbc.gridy = 0;
            gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.SOUTH;
            gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
            gbc.weighty = 1;            
            rightPane.add(buttonsPane, gbc);

            gbc.gridy++;
            gbc.insets = new Insets(8, 0, 0, 0);
            gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
            gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;
            gbc.weighty = 0;
            gbc.gridheight = 2;
            gbc.ipadx = 30;
            gbc.ipady = 30;
            rightPane.add(startBtn, gbc);

            gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.gridx = 0;
            gbc.gridy = 0;
            gbc.weightx = 1;
            gbc.weighty = 1;
            gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
            add(leftPane, gbc);

            gbc.gridx++;
            gbc.weightx = 0;
            gbc.weighty = 1;
            add(rightPane, gbc);
        }

    }

}
```

Now, this is just an example.  You needs might be different which would require using different layout managers or using them in different combinations...

Comment: I copied your code and made a test project.. I get this error "multi-catch statement is not supported in -source 1.6
  (use -source 7 or higher to enable multi-catch statement)" at the UIManager try and catch.

Comment: You have two choices, use Java 7 (set up your IDE to compile with Java 7 and use Java 7 source compatibility) or replace the `catch` statement with a traditional multi stepped `catch`

Comment: @MadProgrammer  You forgot the 3rd option. `catch(Exception)`.  While that is not ideal for production code, it is fine for an MCVE.